# Poor Loc and IndexSlice Performance Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two DataFrames. One has the returns for a range of dates for some stocks. The other has the price and volume by stock and date. In the second DataFrame the price and volume are combined in a MultiIndex with the stocks:

| date | ('adjClose', 'AAPL') | ('volume', 'AAPL') | ('adjClose', 'AMZN') | ('volume', 'AMZN') |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-04-12 00:00:00 | 167.66 | 7.92652e+07 | 3015.75 | 2.75887e+06 |
| 2022-04-13 00:00:00 | 170.4 | 7.06189e+07 | 3110.82 | 2.66954e+06 |
| 2022-04-14 00:00:00 | 165.29 | 7.53294e+07 | 3034.13 | 2.57991e+06 |

The returns DataFrame has dates as indexes and non-MultiIndex stock columns. I'm trying to slice the dates and stocks of the returns DataFrame in the prices and volumes DataFrame. With IndexSlice i have the following:

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df_prices = df_prices.loc[df_return.index, idx[:, df_return.columns]]
```

`df_return` has a shape `df_return.shape=(22, 11224)` and `df_prices`has `df_prices.shape=(821, 22488)`

With said formula it takes 4.94 seconds to complete the slicing. I've tried constructing a MultiIndex from product with the columns in `df_return` and a list `['adjClose','volume']` and the results are instantaneous:

```
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["adjClose", "volume"], df_return.columns])
df_prices = df_prices.loc[df_return.index, cols]
```

What could be causing this delay with IndexSlice? it's not that intuitive that creating a new MultiIndex is faster than using IndexSlice

Thanks!

Comment: Kindly share the dataframe as a dict: `df.to_dict()`.

Comment: @sammywemmy heres the links for csv (couldnt get the dict) files of both DataFrames. df_returns: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cecpmELUeKGtpjR4Fp-UVUQ_vpKDrTwj/view?usp=sharing df_prices:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1t1kwUZF8gbv5la4FzRB_2PBGG1O0Ayp6/view?usp=sharing

Comment: i suspect a cartesian product is generated for the first option (and the cartesian is going to be alot); building the MultiIndex trims it down to specifics, a faster option though, especially as you have one level would be an isin: ``df.loc[:, df.columns.isin(returns.columns, level=1)]``, this runs in 975us on my PC, and conveniently you do not have to build a MultiIndex. I'd say loc on multiindexes is a convenience, there are no performance gains per se (convenience vs performance), and you are better off slicing one level after the other(df.loc.loc.loc ...) if that is possible, or use `isin`

Comment: @sammywemmy thanks a lot. In terms on maintenance I think it’s also better using Loc. do you have any resources to understand the Cartesian product?

Comment: my suspicion regarding Cartesian product is just a hunch; think of it this way, `idx[:, df_return.columns]`, will build a combination of every value in the first level, with every value in df_returns.columns, which is a lot; compare the output to what you get from the MultiIndex you created, and that is way less; you even get less with the boolean approach of `isin`. A certain way to verify this is from the source code, coupled with a debugger. google Cartesian product(not unique to pandas) - like a cross join